# How to speed up creating MySQL table from large CSV file?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am currently using MySQL Workbench to create a table by importing a large CSV file. The CSV file has around 5 million records and 100 columns.

However, the importing process is extremely slow (the process has been running for two hours). I probably need to reduce the number of records or columns, which is not ideal, but would probably be worth it if it reduces the time required significantly.

Which is more likely to reduce import time more: halving the number of records, or halving the number of columns? (And is there a faster way to do the import compared to using the GUI as described [in this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-table.html)?)

Comment: Can you show the `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table` statement in which you import?  And some lines from the CSV so we have a feeling whats imported?

Comment: The Wizard does everything automatically without me having to write any SQL statements. 
I can't show the CSV but it is pretty standard (strings and numbers, each field is less than 30 characters). But I managed to import everything after another hour or so, so I guess my problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import the CSV to MySQL by query:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' 
INTO TABLE my_table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this. Just curious, why is it faster than using the GUI import wizard?

Comment: @wwl mysql-workbench most likely almost does the same `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data.csv' ... ` under the hood.. As this query requires the CVS to be existing on the MySQL Server file storage where `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ` does not and needs to upload the file from local to the server.

Comment: The GUI import inserts rows sequentially. This can be incredibly slow.